# Why "Do I know you" not "Do you know me"?

Tags: questions

When two people meet, and one of them says hello but the other one can't recognize him or her, the other one would ask "Do *I* know you?"

I know this is natural for English speakers but it could be strange for some non  native speakers like me.
 Because in this situation I would ask "Do *you* know me?"

Why do English speakers ask in this way?
From a common-sense standpoint, it is strange to ask others whether I know someone or not.

Comment: I dunno, to me it's pretty clear that if someone greets me, they (think they) know me, so it's nonsensical to ask "do you know me".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Do I know you?" is an idiomatic expression that could be used when you can't recognize a stranger who says "Hi!" to you. Depending on tone and intonation, it could be interpreted as cold rejection uttered to avoid him/her or friendly gesture to ask him/her to elaborate on where/when/how they met before.

"Do you know me?" could sound more rude and cold than "Do I know you?".

There are other English expressions using this construction, for example:

> Did I miss something?

It asks others to tell the questioner what happened while (s)he was absent. Using your explanation, the question sounds weird because it asks others whether **I** missed something or not.

Answer (score 4):

Let's say I run into you in the grocery store.  You are pleased to see me and say hi effusively.  But I don't recognize you.  I'm quickly scanning my memory -- should I be remembering this person?  "Do I know you?  (Should I be remembering you?") At this point you will take pity on me and tell me how we met, where we interacted.

I don't say "Do you know me?" because clearly you do.

Comment: Your last sentence was interesting.
And when I say "Do you know me?" it also implies 'I think I don't know you, but are you sure you really know me?' Thanks anyway.

Comment: ... Yes, 'Do I know you?' is more polite, conceding the (potential) failing to be the speaker's.

Answer (score 0):

"*Do I know you?*" is more polite and natural than "*Do you know me?*" If I ask you "Do you know me?" and you actually don't remember me you might be embarrassed. "Do I know you" moves this embarrassment feeling to you.

"*Do you know me?*" can also have a connotation that I know you and I expect you to remember me.

Answer (score -1):

Phil Collins - Wear My Hat Lyrics:

I said '**Listen pal do I know you**? Have we ever met?
Why do you want my name on this little piece of paper?'

It clearly means two things:

1. You don't know the person, but he knows you.
2. You know the person, but you can't recognize them.